# Is there any alternative for task manager in Ubuntu?

Tags: task-management

In Windows, we have the Windows task manager which can be used when the system becomes stuck or any programs become stuck (ie, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>). We can close the hung programs using this. I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu, are there any alternatives in `Ubuntu` for this purpose?

Comment: We have the same?  gnome-system-monitor is is called.

Comment: @Rinzwind how can i call 'gnome-system-monitor'

Comment: how i can install that,if you post that as answer i will upvote it

Comment: That is installed by default. Just start it. Plus I have seen in attached to a keypress too (but do not know the shortcut ;-))

Comment: See here: [Use Ctrl+Alt+Del to Launch Task Manager on Ubuntu](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/use-ctrl-alt-del-task-manager-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xkill ... you can always open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run `xkill`, then click on the window of the program that does not respond.

xkill must be installed beforehand, but is available in the official Ubuntu repositories.

Alternatively you can open the terminal, run `top` to determine the pid of the programm you want to close. Hit <kbd>q</kbd> to exit top, then run `kill [pid]`

Comment: it is working..but the terminal become stuck this time